# Alternative to heapallocation when returning a uppcasted pointer in a method

Tags: c++11, pointers, heap-memory

The problem that I have is that I'm not allowed to use any heap allocation. And I've got a function that needs to return a pointer to an abstract class.

Example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual Base* func() = 0;
};

class Foo : public Base
{
    Base* func() override
    {
        // return new Foo{}; // usual approach with heap allocation

        // Foo result{}; // undefined behaviour.
        // return &result;
    }
};
```

This example might be a little over simplified, but it shows the problem. How could I implement Foo::func without heap allocation?

Comment: Does `func` need to return a pointer to the same object it was called on? Then simply `return this;` If it's supposed to return a pointer to some other object, then where should storage for that object come from, if not the heap? How is the lifetime of this new object is expected to be managed? Figure out the design, and the implementation would follow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be an option for you: you could pass the address of the memory where the new `Foo` object is to be created to the function and then create the object using placement `new`.

This memory, then, could be on the stack, avoiding heap allocations. Of course you can also pass previously heap-allocated memory, which would still avoid an allocation at the point of creation in `Foo::func`.

See below:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual Base* func(std::byte*) = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Foo : public Base
{
public:
    Base* func(std::byte* pMem) override
    {
        return new (pMem) Foo{};
    }
};

int main() {

    // Buffer on stack
    std::byte buf[sizeof(Foo)];

    Foo f{};
    auto pNew = f.func(buf);

    // Manually call destructor before buffer goes out of scope
    pNew->~Base();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've actually gone with a similar approach like this, but the example way oversimplifys the problem because I want this to be generic and type safe, because its used in a library with which the user will interact. I'll open up a new question for my approach because I've found out that it has undefined behavior in it.