# Undefined behavior in replacement for polymorphism with out Pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, vtable

I've recently asked about this on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68526537/alternative-to-heapallocation-when-returning-a-uppcasted-pointer-in-a-method/68541223#68541223). And I've gone with this generic approach:

```
#define COFFEE_GEN_GENERIC_VALUE(CLASS_TYPE) using GenericValue##CLASS_TYPE = coffee::utils::GenericValue<CLASS_TYPE, COFFEE_GENERIC_VALUE_CONFIG_MAX_DERIVED_SIZE_OF_##CLASS_TYPE>

template<typename Base, size_t MaxDerivedSize>
class GenericValue
{
private:
    char buffer[MaxDerivedSize];

public:
    GenericValue() = default;

    template<typename Derived, typename... ConstructorArgs>
    static GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize> create(ConstructorArgs... args)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value, "Derived must derive from Base.");
        static_assert(sizeof(Derived) <= MaxDerivedSize, "The size specified with the macro COFFEE_GenericValueMaxSize is to small.");
        GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize> result{};
        new ((Derived*) result.buffer) Derived{args...};
        return result;
    }

    template<typename Derived>            
    static GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize> from(Derived* toCopy)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value, "Derived must derive from Base.");
        static_assert(sizeof(Derived) <= sizeof(MaxDerivedSize), "The size specified with the macro COFFEE_GenericValueMaxSize is to small.");
        GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize> result{};
        memcopy(result.buffer, toCopy, sizeof(Derived));
        return result;
    }
    
    GenericValue(const GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize>& other)
    {
        memcopy(buffer, other.buffer, MaxDerivedSize);
    }
    
    GenericValue(GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize>&& other)
    {
        memcopy(buffer, other.buffer, MaxDerivedSize);
    }

    GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize>& operator=(const GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize>& other)
    {
        memcopy(buffer, other.buffer, MaxDerivedSize);
        return *this;
    }
    
    GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize>& operator=(GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize>&& other)
    {
        coffee::utils::copy(buffer, other.buffer, MaxDerivedSize);
        return *this;
    }

    Base& operator*()
    {
        return *(Base*)buffer;
    }

    Base* operator->()
    {
        return (Base*)buffer;
    }
}
```

I had the idea for this form [this website](https://barrgroup.com/embedded-systems/how-to/polymorphism-no-heap-memory) and its kind of the same as the awnser from @Matthias Grün on my old question.
You use the `COFFEE_GEN_GENERIC_VALUE` macro to create a typedef for `GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize>` the size will be passed to it with a second macro. This is so that my library can generate the appropriate `GenericValue` types that will be used for the specific base class. The basic idea behind it is that you store the whole instance of the derived type with it's vtable in `buffer`. You can than copy it just like a regular rvalue.

Unfortunately doe copying only some times works and I have no idea why, based on my knowledge this would not be a problem. If I remove the copy operators and constructor and just use the class as a wrapper for `new` it works great (except the objects aren't realy copied).

Does any body know what the problem could be?

I will post a specific example when I found an edge case for which I don't have to post my whole project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memcpy` of data that isn't "plain old data" is undefined behavior.  When you are doing shenanigans, avoid undefined behavior.

So the first thing you need to do this is to store a pointer-to-copy operation beside your buffer.  Then when you copy your buffer, instead of memcpy, you call that pointer-to-copy operation.

A simple way to do this is with a `void(*)(void const* src, void* dst)` function pointer that copies from `src` to `dst`.

Casting memory to a type it isn't and using that pointer is undefined behavior.

So the second thing you need to do is to store a way to get the pointer-to-base from the memory buffer.  A simple way to do this is to store a `Base*(*)(void*)` function pointer, and pass it a pointer to the buffer.

For the cost of a bit of indirection, you can reduce the per-instance overhead to a single pointer like this.

```
struct BasicVTable {
  void(* destroy)(void*) = 0;
  template<class T>
  static BasicVTable make() {
    return {[](void* ptr){ static_cast<T*>(ptr)->~T(); }};
  }
  template<class T>
  static auto const* get() {
    static const auto vtable = make<T>();
    return &vtable;
  }
};
struct RegularVTable : BasicVTable {
  void(*assign)(void const* src, void* dst) = 0;
  void(*assign_move)(void* src, void* dst) = 0;
  void(*copy)(void const* src, void* dst) = 0;
  void(*move)(void* src, void* dst) = 0;

  
  template<class T>
  static RegularVTable make() {
    return {
      BasicVTable::template make<T>(),
      [](void const* src, void* dst) {
        *static_cast<T*>(dst) = *static_cast<T const*>(src);
      },
      [](void* src, void* dst) {
        *static_cast<T*>(dst) = std::move(*static_cast<T*>(src));
      },
      [](void const* src, void* dst) {
        ::new(dst) T(*static_cast<T const*>(src));
      },
      [](void* src, void* dst) {
        ::new(dst) T(std::move(*static_cast<T*>(src)));
      }
    };
  }
  template<class T>
  static auto const* get() {
    static const auto vtable = make<T>();
    return &vtable;
  }
};

template<class Base>
struct PolyBaseVTable : RegularVTable {
  Base*(*GetBase)(void* src) = 0;
  Base const*(*cGetBase)(void const* src) = 0;

  template<class T>
  static PolyBaseVTable make() {
    return {
      RegularVTable::make<T>(),
      [](void* src)->Base* {
        return static_cast<T*>(src);
      },
      [](void const* src)->Base const* {
        return static_cast<T const*>(src);
      }
    };
  }

  template<class T>
  static auto const* get() {
    static const auto vtable = make<T>();
    return &vtable;
  }
};
```

now we modify your `GenericValue`:

```
template<typename Base, size_t MaxDerivedSize>
class GenericValue
{
private:
  PolyBaseVTable<Base> const* vtable = nullptr;
  char buffer[MaxDerivedSize];
```

to store an extra pointer.

We do some slight modifications:

```
template<typename Derived, typename... ConstructorArgs>
static GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize> create(ConstructorArgs... args)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value, "Derived must derive from Base.");
    static_assert(sizeof(Derived) <= MaxDerivedSize, "The size specified with the macro COFFEE_GenericValueMaxSize is to small.");
    GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize> result{};
    ::new ((void*) result.buffer) Derived{args...}; // void* here
    result.vtable = PolyBaseVTable<Base>::template get<Derived>();
    return result;
}
```

where we initialize the `vtable` after we construct the object.

Your `from` is nonsense.  It is just another `create`.

Copy construct is then:

```
GenericValue(const GenericValue<Base, MaxDerivedSize>& other)
{
  if (!other.vtable) return;
  other.vtable->copy( &other.buffer, &buffer );
  vtable = other.vtable;
}
```

with the other assignment/move operations working similarly.  Assignment is a bit of a pain:

```
GenericValue& operator=(const GenericValue& other)
{
  if (vtable != other.vtable)
  {
    if (vtable) vtable->destroy(&buffer);
    vtable = nullptr;
    if (other.vtable)
    {
        other.vtable->copy(&other.buffer, &buffer);
        vtable=other.vtable;
        return *this;
    }
  }
  if (!vtable) return *this;
  vtable->assign( &other.buffer, &buffer );
  return *this;
}
```

as you have to handle a type-change possibility.

For base access:

```
Base* operator->()
{
  if (!vtable) return nullptr;
  return vtable->GetBase( &buffer );
}
Base const* operator->() const
{
  if (!vtable) return nullptr;
  return vtable->cGetBase( &buffer );
}
```

easy peasy.

Now, this code *did* use extended aggregate rules from after [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), so the `static make` functions in the vtable will have to be modified to be more verbose if you are restricted to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).  But there is nothing really tricky there.

Also, the automatic return type deduction (my use of `auto` in a few spots) may have to be replaced with actual types.  The intended type isn't that hard to work out, I just didn't, because I didn't want to repeat myself there.

You also need to invoke `vtable->destroy` on `~GenericValue` of course.

---

Now, you may note I made the table of operations a `vtable`.  This is because I'm reimplementing a simple version of classic C++ based polymorphism in a C-with-enhanced-C++-code-generation way.

You can actually use this to implement operations other than cast-to-base, to avoid an extra vtable hit.  I'd only consider this in cases where the performance of the extra vtable hit is detected, or when I want to store hedrogenous objects (like how `std::function` works) and support polymorphism on them.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/xd3z8PT14) of this in operation.

[C++11 version](https://godbolt.org/z/nxKnvdnxW).

Comment: I've just started rewriting it for c++-11, I'll post the code as soon as I'm done (probably tomorrow). Thank you very much @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont.

Comment: @GianLaager Wrote C++11 version here https://godbolt.org/z/nxKnvdnxW

Comment: Great, I‘m going to try to use normal c++ inheritance in the vtables, personally I don‘t really like this implementation of the vtables. Posting it when I figured it out.

Comment: @gian then you need to store a base pointer external to the buffer, and a placement copy/move/assign/move assign virtual methods that return the new base pointer.

Comment: Is there any chance this could be done less memory consuming? I asked this question to use it in an embedded system, but even with these `-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -s` optimization flags the vtable creation takes up 7.1kb of flash.